# Laravel/breeze not working with sqlite database

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, breeze

I'm trying the new laravel/breeze. I'm using Ubuntu and created the project with the following commands:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^8.0

composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install

npm install && npm run dev

php artisan serve
```

Then, i created a database.sqlite in database folder, made the php artisan migrate and then php artisan serve. But this error is returning:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: sessions (SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = CDPZlQLRnWq3YiCmNjX76bCumANwCL2Vykcbl2u4 limit 1)
```

Does anyone know what's going on? I'm not that experienced with laravel environments, maybe i forgot something in the beginning.

Comment: Did you change you settings in `.env`? Or does `php artisan breeze:install` do that?

Comment: I followed a tutorial and modified it manually to:

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=laravel
#DB_USERNAME=root
#DB_PASSWORD=

Is this right?

Comment: That should be enough, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default driver for sessions in your `.env` file is `SESSION_DRIVER=file`.
You seem to have changed that to use your database instead.
For this to work you need a table in your database to store session information.
You can do this by running

```
php artisan session:table
```

and then

```
php artisan migrate
```

to migrate/create the database table.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you so much!